# How can you set HWND_TOPMOST on Window running at higher privilege?

Tags: shell, winapi, gdi

Is there a method that allows an app running at a lower privilege to use `SetWindowPos()` to change the `HWND_TOPMOST` flag for a Window running at a higher privilege?

I recall, in the back of my mind, different API's available to allow things like that but I don't recall the specifics.

TIA!!

Comment: This seems like it would be a security hole. A low privilege app could remove topmost from a high privilege password prompt and then display its own fake password prompt.

Comment: Couldn't it already do that since it could set topmost on itself to overlay and the latest topmost is topmost or does the topmost logic use privilege level too?

Comment: Depends on how low privilege the low privilege app is.

Comment: Similar case: [Cant to move on-screen keyboard window](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3764c9b2-06a6-45ce-b294-7e8cc72fba3c/cant-to-move-onscreen-keyboard-window?forum=vcgeneral)...I'm more interested in those APIs you mentioned. Maybe it's an API like elevated privileges?